# Empty result in second level of kartik depdrop in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Here am trying Dependent dropdown using kartik depdrop yii2 extension . the process of this dependent dropdown is, if i select a productname it will show me the dependent batchno, then if select a batchno, it will show the dependent itemid.

Actually first level is working perfectly, if i select a productname, it will show me batchno, this action is working perfectly, but the problem on the second level. if i select a batchno it need to show me a itemid, this action is not working

And am getting error as this image - [image: Empty Result]

Controller

```
public function actionSubcat() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            $out = Productbatch::getBatchNo($cat_id);
            echo Json::encode($out);
            // the getSubCatList function will query the database based on the
            // cat_id and return an array like below:
            // [
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
            // ]
            //echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
    }

    public function actionProd() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $ids = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        $cat_id = empty($ids[0]) ? null : $ids[0];
        $subcat_id = empty($ids[1]) ? null : $ids[1];
        if ($cat_id != null) {
           $data = Productbatch::getItemid($cat_id, $subcat_id);
            /**
             * the getProdList function will query the database based on the
             * cat_id and sub_cat_id and return an array like below:
             *  [
             *      'out'=>[
             *          ['id'=>'<prod-id-1>', 'name'=>'<prod-name1>'],
             *          ['id'=>'<prod_id_2>', 'name'=>'<prod-name2>']
             *       ],
             *       'selected'=>'<prod-id-1>'
             *  ]
             */
           echo Json::encode($out);
           //echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>$data['selected']]);
           return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}
```

_form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productnames::find()->all(),'productnames_productname','productnames_productname'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product Name', 'id' => 'cat-id'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'batchno')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id'],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['cat-id'],
        'placeholder'=>'Select BatchNo',
        'url'=>Url::to(['/production/productbatch/subcat'])
    ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'itemid')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['cat-id', 'subcat-id'],
        'placeholder'=>'Select ItemId',
        'url'=>Url::to(['/production/productbatch/prod'])
    ]
    ]); ?>
```

Model

```
public static function getBatchNo($cat_id)
    {
        $out = [];
        $data = Productbatch::find()
                ->where(['productname' => $cat_id])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
        foreach ($data as $dat) {
            $out[] = ['id' => $dat['itemid'], 'name' => $dat['batchno']];
        }
        return $output = [
            'output' => $out,
            'selected' => ''
        ];
    }

    public static function getItemid($cat_id, $subcat_id)
    {
        $out = [];
        $data = Productbatch::find()
                ->where(['productname' => $cat_id])
                ->andWhere(['batchno' => $subcat_id])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();

        $selected = '';

        foreach ($data as $dat => $datas) {
            $out[] = ['id' => $datas['itemid'], 'name' => $datas['itemid']];

            if($dat == 0){
                    $aux = $datas['itemid'];
                }

            ($datas['productname'] == $cat_id) ? $selected = $cat_id : $selected = $aux;

        }
        return $output = [
            'output' => $out,
            'selected' => $selected
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need do like this in your controller. You have to create new action in controller .

```
public function actionState() {
        $country_id = $_POST['depdrop_parents'][0];
        $state = State::find()->where(['country_id' => $country_id])->all();
        $all_state = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($state as $value) {
            $all_state[$i]['id'] = $value['state_id'];
            $all_state[$i]['name'] = $value['state_name'];
            $i++;
        }
        echo Json::encode(['output' => $all_state, 'selected' => '']);
        return;
    }
```

i also suffered from this problem but finally I solved this issue..

Comment: I think I already have actionSubcat and actionProd in my controller. Can you have a look at my controller and tell me what modification I need to do?

Comment: You need to create one array and use foreach to store all subcat as show in my controller and convert it into json and return it .. is work for me ..

Comment: I think your query is not working try this:  $model = User::find()->where("productname = $cat_id and batchno = $subcat_id")->all();

Comment: try : $model = User::find()
                ->where('productname = :productname', [':productname' => $cat_id])
                ->andWhere('batchno = :batchno', [':batchno' => $subcat_id])
                ->all();

Comment: ha ha ... finally find it echo Json::encode( $data) not a echo Json::encode($out); in your actionProd()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109633/discussion-between-rahul-pawar-and-tanmay-mukherjee).

Comment: can u explain your problem in detail.